# Is it possible to negate a DynamoDB ConditionCheck in a WriteTransaction?

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I'm using DynamoDB transactions and wondering if I can conditionally write to my database if and only if a certain [ConditionCheck](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_ConditionCheck.html) in my transaction fails. I would just restructure my ConditionCheck to search for the reverse of my current check, but with my current table design it would require some sort of `not_begins_with` query which isn't supported. Any chance someone knows of some sort of negation operator for ConditionChecks or the DynamoDB Java SDK that I can't find?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the underlying condition expression string can support NOT as an operator.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ConditionExpressions.html